# How to convert array to vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to convert the following data array into a row vector in Matlab, but I have no idea how to do so.

Data array:

```
0    1    2
3    4    5
6    7    8
9    10   11
```

Row vector:

```
0    1    2   3   4   5   6    7    8    9    10   11
```

Comment: Please consider taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how SO works. Asking for a solution without showing what you have done is considered poor practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `reshape`. Assuming your initial array is `A`:

```
v = reshape (A', [numel(A) 1])';
```

Best,

Comment: The function of reshape has already solved my problem.Thank you .